# How do you check your road bike tires for wear?

Tags: maintenance, road-bike, tire

What is the best way to determine if your tires need to be replaced?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not getting regular punctures due to the thin-ness of the tire or the fabric of the tire is showing/damaged, you can keep the tires on ([Sheldon](http://sheldonbrown.com/tires.html#replacement)). Unlike a car tire, a tubular tire just requires the tire portion to prevent the tube from getting cut up. And road tires should be smooth since you don't need tread.

Answer (score 1):

A number of the Continental models actually have two small divets in them that you can use to gauge the wear level of the tire. If present, I use those. Otherwise I look for excessive numbers of deep cuts in the tire, or some of the tire fabric showing through through the rubber.